# UITableView swipe return animation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swipe

I have a table, and I noticed that when I do the "swipe to delete", the red button is animated only the first time, the return (if I do another swipe) disappears without animation. These are the methods I use for this step:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

...

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView reloadData];

}
```

I forgot something to animate the return?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, leave out the `[tableView reloadData];`. You only need to reload the table in `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:etc:`, and arguably not even then—it’s better to use the UITableView method `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. Reloading it is unnecessary and is why your delete button is disappearing instead of animating out.

Comment: the problem may be that the cells are custom cells?